# Array.find() method usage with req.param in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, req

I am trying to understand basics of "express" package of JS and I am stuck with getting array elements based on index that comes from URL.

Here is my code, this is almost a copy of udemy instructor's code, I was writing simultaneosly.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = new express();

const users = [
    { id: 1 , name: "harun" },
    { id: 2 , name:"apo" },
    { id: 3 , name: "ogi" }
]


app.get('/', (req,res) => {
    res.send("Welcome to my Page");
});

app.get('/api/users', (req,res) => {
    console.table(users);
    res.send(users);
});

app.get('/api/users/:id', (req,res) => {
    const user = users.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.param.id));
    if(user === null) res.status(404).send("User is not found");
    res.send(user);
});


const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port: ${port}`));
```

Localhost page reaches status 404, user is not found.
Problem is ,most probably, about the line:

```
 const user = users.find(c => c.id === parseInt(req.param.id));
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Start debugging your code, like checking the value of `req.param.id` for example. However, take in mind that [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns `undefined` when no element is found, not `null`.

Comment: What localhost url are you visiting?

Comment: localhost:3000/api/users/1

Comment: also, I changed " user === null " part to  " !user " but still same status 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking in the wrong place.
Express provides the route params in the `req.params` not the `req.param`.

Maybe changing it to:
`parseInt(req.params.id, 10)` will help you

Comment: but req.params is not recognized in typescript

Comment: Hey! You are right, it gives me the desired result but what is the difference between param and params?

Comment: Just ran a `toString` on `req.param` and it appears to be a function that returns the params. Please mark this answer as correct if it worked for you :)